# JS to jQuery! - Combobox solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

i have this code working in js :

```
let selecter = document.getElementById("select");
for (let i = 0; i < selecter.children.length; i++) {
    selecter.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(i);
}
```

so i tried to convert this into jQuery. My result is kinda mixed up and i tried a few variations but none worked.

maybe you guys can show me the right way to handle this.

not working code:

```
let cbx = $("#cbx option:selected");
for (let i = 0; i < cbx.length; i++) {
    cbx.click(function() {
        console.log(cbx.index());
    });
}
```

the goal is to get the index of the choosen field in the combobox after you clicked it.

here is the HTML code for the Combobox:

```
    <div id="cbx-container" class="container">
        <select name="combobox" id ="cbx" class="combobox">
            <option id="oTrue" selected="">True</option>
            <option id="oFalse">False</option>
            <option id="oId1">Identitaet 1</option>
            <option id="oId2">Identitaet 2</option>
            <option id="oNotA">Not A</option>
            <option id="oNotB">Not B</option>
            <option id="oAnd">AND</option>
            <option id="oNand">NAND</option>
            <option id="oOr">OR</option>
            <option id="oNor">NOR</option>
            <option id="oXor">XOR</option>
            <option id="oAequ">Aequivalenz</option>
            <option id="oInhib1">Inhibition 1</option>
            <option id="oInhib2">Inhibition 2</option>
            <option id="oImp1">Implikation 1</option>
            <option id="oImp2">Implikation 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

couldnt find the right solution here, maybe was using the wrong search words.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? I think instead of using ID for the option you should use class.

Comment: sure, i will edit the html into my post!

Comment: if i change it to let 
    cbx = $("combobox option:selected");
i get an index return of -1 instead of 0 for the first item

Comment: If  you have working code, why weigh it down with jQuery? Are you still supporting IE7 or something?

Comment: its for learning, i learn to use jQuery right now, so i wanted to redo a project i did earlier with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that this way workes well:

```
$("#cbx").change(function(){

  let selecter = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  console.log(selecter + " THIS WORKS");

  if (selecter == 0) {
      console.log("0 selected");
  } else {
      console.log("1 selected");
  }
});
```

will try your answeres too & wich method is the newest?
thank you all for your help (sadly cant upvote so far)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you can use index() function combined with find() using "option:selected".

```
$("#cbx").change(function(){
  console.log($(this).find('option:selected').index());
});
```

Example fiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/hbm4qrfm/1/

Answer (score 0):

For what reason do you use id's, instead of value?
Having a list of id's seems kinda weird.

```
value="someVal"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhhc45dc/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected options index like this

```
$("select").on('change', function(){
   console.log(this.selectedIndex)
})
```

here is the fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/marwat/vL4sh11x/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *index* method like below

```
$("#cbx").change(function(){
   console.log($("#cbx :selected").index());
})
```